# Fading in an image from 0 opacity but stopping at .35 then hovering for a opacity of 1?

Tags: html, css

Ive been working on this website for the past 20 minutes maybe and i hit a block. I cant seem to fade my images in ( from 0 opacity ) then stop at .35 opacity then when i hover it turns to 1 opacity. Hope it made sense at all.

```css
@-webkit- animation fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity 1;   
    }
}

@-webkit- animation fadeinicons {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity .35;   
    }
}

@keyframes fadeinicons {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity .35;   
    }
}

.icons {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icons:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.facebook {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeinicons;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.twitter {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeinicons;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

.github {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeinicons;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 11.5s;
}
```

thats my CSS above my html looks like this

```html
<center> 
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011139572310" target="_blank"> <img src="0.png" class="icons" height="95" width="95" class="facebook" /> </a>
        <a  href="https://twitter.com/_moemansour" target="_blank">
        <img src="2.png" class="icons" height="95" width="95" class="twitter" /></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/moemansour" target="_blank">
        <img src="4.png" class="icons" height="95" width="95" class="github" /> 
      </center>
```

It doesnt seem to start off with an opacity of 0 then fade into .35 then when i hover turns into a 1. It works perfectly fine when i dont have the animations running but currently this is what it does.

[Click Here to see the Gyazo Gif](https://gyazo.com/b1bf64226c81d8bb1b977aca02006c07)

I hope i made this as clear, i tried my best. The gif cuts off early but the images remain the same the entire time even after the 3 seconds pass. Thank you all in advance this really means alot!

Answer (score 0):

What i did was to add a class to the link wrappers of your icons - "icon-link".
On that wrapper i set the opacity to be 0.35 and on hover to change to 1.

On the images i added a staggering effect (animation with delay) like you wanted.

This is the final result. I think it fits what you were trying to achieve :)

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeinicons {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.icons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.facebook,
.twitter,
.github {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeinicons;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}
.twitter {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}
.github {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}
.icon-link {
  opacity: 0.35;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <a href="#" class="icon-link" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-512.png" class="icons facebook" height="95" width="95" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="icon-link" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://yolna.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/twitter-circle-logo.png" class="icons twitter" height="95" width="95" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="icon-link" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/github-circled_318-10752.jpg" class="icons github" height="95" width="95" />
  </a>
</center>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you so much! Like the way you did it too, sorry im  a little new to animations. But thank you so much! i would upvote if i could :P

Comment: @MohamedMansour You can mark the answer as correct if it what you were looking for :) (You don't have to upvote)

Answer (score -1):

```
Some of your html snippets are totally wrong. 
     For ex added class attribute twice. 
     Always browsers identifies first defined class attribute and ignores duplication. 
     You also didn't close your anchor tag for the img4.png . Refer https://jsfiddle.net/tt3oycty/2/

<center> 
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011139572310" target="_blank"> <img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg" class="icons facebook" height="95" width="95" class="" /> </a>
        <a  href="https://twitter.com/_moemansour" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg" class="icons twitter" height="95" width="95" class="" /></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/moemansour" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg" class="icons github" height="95" width="95" class="" />
        </a>
 </center>

@-webkit- animation fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity 1;   
    }
}

@-webkit- animation fadeinicons {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity .35;   
    }
}

@keyframes fadeinicons {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity .35;   
    }
}

.icons {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icons:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.facebook {
    opacity: 0.35;
    animation-name: fadeinicons;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

.twitter {
    opacity: 0.35;
    animation-name: fadeinicons;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

.github {
    opacity: 0.35;
    animation-name: fadeinicons;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 11.5s;
}
```